# minimalistic way of redirecting http/s traffic

Tags: iptables, redirect

In my scenario, I dynamically provisioning compute nodes to preform a task - in this scenario, a client is given the IP of the node to access using a specific application that access the application server on a non-standard port.

Now, giving out this IP address, there is a good chance that someone will just enter it in their webbrowser - which would end up sending the packet to the application server that will not be running a webserver.

I would like to however, redirect any of these requests back to the main website for the project, how could I go about doing this in the most minimalistic way possible?

I thought about using

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination ww.xx.yy.zz:80
"" 443
```

however using this - I can not specify the exact page that I want the user to see `example.com/projectPage`, and also, all traffic would then be proxies *through* the appserver, would it not?

I *could* install something like `lighthttpd`, or is there a better way that does not require a dedicated webserver.

Comment: Change the DNS TTL to a low value, and after change the DNS to affect those computer, simpler ?

Comment: please note 80 and 443 use different protocols, and http://...:443 may not work, as well as httpS://...:80